# Netsuite SuiteScript Relationships Events

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

We have a many-to-many relationship between customers and contacts.  We need a way to trigger a script when the adding/removing relationships.  There are no events that fire on client scripts. Also, the adding/removal of these relationships are allowed while viewing a record and don't require editing and/or saving the records to complete the relationship.

Comment: Have you only explored Client Scripts? I'm not sure off the top what events, if any, are triggered by associating/dissociating a Contact with a Customer. If any are triggered at all, it's likely going to be a User Event `beforeSubmit` and `afterSubmit`; I recommend exploring these. Client Scripts are only useful when editing a record directly through the UI.

Comment: Yeah I am using client and user events, but nothing is triggered when relationships are attached or removed. And they happen without having to save or edit the forms.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to make a custom sublist that searches for a customers relationships?

Comment: Which record(s) have you deployed the UE to? Both Contacts and Customers? I'm not surprised the Customer record doesn't trigger anything, but I might actually expect the Contact, since that's the record that's actually changing.

Comment: Good idea, but no luck.  Seams relationships aren't stored on records themselves. Even tried client and user event scripts that apply to 'All Records'.

Comment: I took a look and I don't see any way to do this. It appears the relationship is stored in a record called "companycontact". However, I can't see any way to interact with it except for the UI.